# Create a time bound animation using CSS and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Im trying to create an animation for a landing page. Since the animation runs every time the user refreshes the page or click on the home button, Im trying to limiting the animation to once every one hour. I wrote a javascript for the same, but there seems to be an error. Will be helpful if anyone can point out the mistake I've done.

```js
let animationInterval;
let animationCompleted = false;

function animateOncePerHour() {
  // Check if animation has already been completed
  if (animationCompleted) return;

  // Get the current time
  const currentTime = new Date();
  // Set the next animation time to be 1 hour later
  const nextAnimationTime = new Date(currentTime.getTime() + 60 * 60 * 1000);

  // Start the animation
  document.querySelector('.text').style.animation = 'herot 1s';

  // Set an interval to check the current time and stop the animation when the next animation time is reached
  animationInterval = setInterval(() => {
    const currentTime = new Date();
    if (currentTime >= nextAnimationTime) {
      clearInterval(animationInterval);
      document.querySelector('.text').style.animation = 'none';
      animationCompleted = true;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

// Call the animateOncePerHour function when the page loads
window.onload = animateOncePerHour;
```

```css
.text {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 45%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  animation-name: herot;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  z-index: 1000;
}

@keyframes herot {
  0% {
    font-size: 16rem;
  }
  45% {
    font-size: 10rem;
  }
  50% {
    font-size: 10rem;
  }
  75% {
    font-size: 10rem;
  }
  90% {
    font-size: 10rem;
  }
  100% {
    font-size: 0px;
  }
}

.text {
  font-size: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <h1>NEN</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: PS try not to use `font-size` for animations. There's the GPU accelerable `scale` or `transform` properties.

Comment: Learn how to use LocalStorage to save and read data from a client browser Storage.

Answer (score -1):

The JS loads with the refresh of the page every time, so the variables

```
let animationInterval;
let animationCompleted = false;
```

and

```
new Date();
```

are all generated anew.

You will need some back-end to handle the timers and allow or block the animation.